# Unmet dependencies: install-build-dep.sh "Chromium prerequisites installation"

Tags: installation, apt, dependencies, chromium

I'm trying to install the Chromium prerequisites by running the `install-build-dep.sh` script.

Every time I try to run it I get this output:

```
***r@***r:~/Desktop$ sudo ./install-build-deps.sh --no-chromeos-fonts
This script installs all tools and libraries needed to build Chromium.

For most of the libraries, it can also install debugging symbols, which
will allow you to debug code in the system libraries. Most developers
won't need these symbols.
Do you want me to install them for you (y/N) Y
Installing debugging symbols.
Skipping installation of Chrome OS fonts.
Skipping installation of ARM cross toolchain.
Hit http://archive.canonical.com raring Release.gpg
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com raring Release.gpg                     
Hit http://archive.canonical.com raring Release                      
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com raring Release                                    
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring Release.gpg                               
Hit http://archive.canonical.com raring/partner amd64 Packages       
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com raring/main Sources                     
Hit http://archive.canonical.com raring/partner i386 Packages        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates Release.gpg             
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com raring/main amd64 Packages              
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com raring/main i386 Packages               
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security Release.gpg                      
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                    
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-proposed Release.gpg                      
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports Release.gpg                     
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring Release                         
Ign http://archive.canonical.com raring/partner Translation-en_US              
Ign http://archive.canonical.com raring/partner Translation-en                 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates Release                 
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                    
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security Release                
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com raring/main Translation-en_US                     
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com raring/main Translation-en              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-proposed Release
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports Release                
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/main Sources                     
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/main i386 Packages
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted i386 Packages         
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/main Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/multiverse Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/restricted Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/main Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/multiverse Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/restricted Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/main i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/main Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe Translation-en
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-proposed/restricted Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-proposed/main Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-proposed/multiverse Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-proposed/universe Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-proposed/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-proposed/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-proposed/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-proposed/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-proposed/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-proposed/main i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-proposed/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-proposed/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-proposed/main Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-proposed/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-proposed/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-proposed/universe Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/restricted Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/main Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/multiverse Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/universe Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/main i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/main Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/universe Translation-en
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-proposed/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-proposed/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-proposed/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-proposed/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/universe Translation-en_US
Reading package lists... Done
Finding missing packages...
Packages required:  apache2.2-bin bison curl elfutils fakeroot flex g++ gperf language-pack-fr libapache2-mod-php5 libasound2-dev libbz2-dev libcairo2-dev libcups2-dev libcurl4-gnutls-dev libelf-dev libgconf2-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libglib2.0-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libgnome-keyring-dev libgtk2.0-dev libkrb5-dev libnspr4-dev libnss3-dev libpam0g-dev libpci-dev libpulse-dev libsctp-dev libspeechd-dev libsqlite3-dev libssl-dev libudev-dev libwww-perl libxslt1-dev libxss-dev libxt-dev libxtst-dev mesa-common-dev metacity patch perl php5-cgi pkg-config python python-cherrypy3 python-dev python-psutil rpm ruby subversion ttf-dejavu-core ttf-indic-fonts ttf-kochi-gothic ttf-kochi-mincho ttf-thai-tlwg wdiff git-core libbluetooth-dev libc6-i386 lib32gcc1 lib32stdc++6 ttf-mscorefonts-installer libjpeg-dev libudev1 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libasound2 libcairo2 libcups2 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libfreetype6 libglib2.0-0 libgnome-keyring0 libgtk2.0-0 libpam0g libpango1.0-0 libpci3 libpcre3 libpixman-1-0 libpng12-0 libspeechd2 libstdc++6 libsqlite3-0 libx11-6 libxau6 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxdmcp6 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxinerama1 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxtst6 zlib1g libpulse0 libbz2-1.0 libcurl4-gnutls-dev libnspr4 libnss3 appmenu-gtk libatk1.0-dbg libc6-dbg libcairo2-dbg libfontconfig1-dbg libglib2.0-0-dbg libgtk2.0-0-dbg libpango1.0-0-dbg libpcre3-dbg libpixman-1-0-dbg libsqlite3-0-dbg libx11-6-dbg libxau6-dbg libxcb1-dbg libxcomposite1-dbg libxcursor1-dbg libxdamage1-dbg libxdmcp6-dbg libxext6-dbg libxfixes3-dbg libxi6-dbg libxinerama1-dbg libxrandr2-dbg libxrender1-dbg libxtst6-dbg zlib1g-dbg libnspr4-dbg libnss3-dbg

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
The following command failed:  sudo apt-get install --reinstall apache2.2-bin bison curl elfutils fakeroot flex g++ gperf language-pack-fr libapache2-mod-php5 libasound2-dev libbz2-dev libcairo2-dev libcups2-dev libcurl4-gnutls-dev libelf-dev libgconf2-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libglib2.0-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libgnome-keyring-dev libgtk2.0-dev libkrb5-dev libnspr4-dev libnss3-dev libpam0g-dev libpci-dev libpulse-dev libsctp-dev libspeechd-dev libsqlite3-dev libssl-dev libudev-dev libwww-perl libxslt1-dev libxss-dev libxt-dev libxtst-dev mesa-common-dev metacity patch perl php5-cgi pkg-config python python-cherrypy3 python-dev python-psutil rpm ruby subversion ttf-dejavu-core ttf-indic-fonts ttf-kochi-gothic ttf-kochi-mincho ttf-thai-tlwg wdiff git-core libbluetooth-dev libc6-i386 lib32gcc1 lib32stdc++6 ttf-mscorefonts-installer libjpeg-dev libudev1 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libasound2 libcairo2 libcups2 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libfreetype6 libglib2.0-0 libgnome-keyring0 libgtk2.0-0 libpam0g libpango1.0-0 libpci3 libpcre3 libpixman-1-0 libpng12-0 libspeechd2 libstdc++6 libsqlite3-0 libx11-6 libxau6 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxdmcp6 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxinerama1 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxtst6 zlib1g libpulse0 libbz2-1.0 libcurl4-gnutls-dev libnspr4 libnss3 appmenu-gtk libatk1.0-dbg libc6-dbg libcairo2-dbg libfontconfig1-dbg libglib2.0-0-dbg libgtk2.0-0-dbg libpango1.0-0-dbg libpcre3-dbg libpixman-1-0-dbg libsqlite3-0-dbg libx11-6-dbg libxau6-dbg libxcb1-dbg libxcomposite1-dbg libxcursor1-dbg libxdamage1-dbg libxdmcp6-dbg libxext6-dbg libxfixes3-dbg libxi6-dbg libxinerama1-dbg libxrandr2-dbg libxrender1-dbg libxtst6-dbg zlib1g-dbg libnspr4-dbg libnss3-dbg

It produces the following output:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Reinstallation of lib32gcc1 is not possible, it cannot be downloaded.
Reinstallation of libstdc++6 is not possible, it cannot be downloaded.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 g++ : Depends: cpp (>= 4:4.7.3-1ubuntu10) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: gcc (>= 4:4.7.3-1ubuntu10) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: g++-4.7 (>= 4.7.3-1~) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: gcc-4.7 (>= 4.7.3-1~) but it is not going to be installed
 lib32stdc++6 : Depends: gcc-4.7-base (= 4.7.3-1ubuntu1) but 4.7.3-2ubuntu1~12.04 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

You will have to install the above packages yourself.
```

Comment: Is this a raring system? Because for some reason it seems like you have the toolchain test build for precise for gcc-4.7-base, though I didn't see any ppas in the `apt-get update` output. If you check `apt-cache policy gcc-4.7-base` you will probably see that it is manually installed. You'll likely have to revert that to the repo version before the install will succeed.

Comment: never mind, I managed to re-install Ubuntu 13.04 from scratch instead of the upgrade I've done, it worked fine, the problem was when the upgrade was in process some packages was installed properly.